# React Native call a function in a render method

Tags: react-native

First of all i created a renderIf.js like

```
export default function renderIf (condition, content) {
if(condition)
{
    return content;
}
else
{
    return null;
}}
```

After this i import renderIf.js in my rootnavigation.js like this, but somethings going wrong.

```
render () {
    return(
        renderIf(this.state.tokenStatus,
            <LoginNavigator />
        ),
        renderIf(!this.state.tokenStatus,
            <RootStackNavigator />
        )
    )
}
```

If tokenStatus false renderIf working but when i give true its just a blank screen.Where i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used a comma (,) in your return statement

```
render() {
    return (
       ....
       ,
       ....
    );
}
```

Which caused the last statement to be the final statement of you render function. Hence, only valid statement of you render method is

```
renderIf(!this.state.tokenStatus,
    <RootStackNavigator />
)
```

So if `token` is false, you are getting a working solution otherwise null is returned from `render` method.

Hope this will help!

**UPDATE:**

A working solution will be to return an array in your `render` method.

Please consider the following snippet

```
export default function renderIf(condition, comp) {
    return condition ? comp : null;
}

render () {
  return([
    renderIf(this.state.tokenStatus,
        <LoginNavigator />
    ),
    renderIf(!this.state.tokenStatus,
        <RootStackNavigator />
    )
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your function calls in curly braces if they’re part of the returned JSX. However for your code, a simple ternary statement would do:

```
render () {
    return this.state.tokenStatus ? (<LoginNavigator />) : (<RootStackNavigator />);
}
```